# GUI ImageIcon deck of cards

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

So I have this program I'm working on that displays 3 random cards in the frame with labels. So far I have it to assign a deck of cards to an array of ImageIcons and then shuffle them. My question is, How do I go about assigning them to JLabels now. Forgive me for the stupid question, as I know it is something simple but I'm very new to using GUI and it frightens me lol

here's my code so far:

```
package assignment2;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
public class Assignment2 extends JFrame{
    public Assignment2(){

        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,5,5));
        add(new JLabel()); ///display one random card
        add(new JLabel()); ////display another random card
        add(new JLabel()); ////display another random card
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Assignment2 frame = new Assignment2();
        frame.setTitle("MAIN TO THE FRAME");
        frame.setSize(600,300);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final int FINAL_CARDS_NUMBER = 54;

        ImageIcon deckOfCards [] = new ImageIcon [FINAL_CARDS_NUMBER];

        for(int i = 0; i <FINAL_CARDS_NUMBER; i++){
            deckOfCards[i] = new ImageIcon("C:/card/" + (i + 1) + ".png");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < FINAL_CARDS_NUMBER; i++) {
            int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (FINAL_CARDS_NUMBER-i));
            ImageIcon t = deckOfCards[r];
            deckOfCards[r] = deckOfCards[i];
            deckOfCards[i] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, remove the 3 lines where you add the labels:

```
add(new JLabel());
```

Then, in the place where you are getting the `ImageIcon`, do this:

```
ImageIcon t = deckOfCards[r];
JLabel label = new JLabel(t);
add(label);
```

However, I suggest you don't set the layout and add components directly to your `JFrame`. You would better create a new `JPanel` and add that to the content pane of your `JFrame`:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

Then, when you add the labels, add them to the panel.

```
panel.add(new JLabel(t));
```

Now that you updated the question, I am updating the answer below.
First, declare 3 `JLabel`, instantiate them and add them to the panel as explained above.

```
JLabel card1 = new JLabel();
JLabel card2 = new JLabel();
JLabel card3 = new JLabel();
```

Then, after you read the `ImageIcon` for each, you can set the `JLabel` image this way:

```
card1.setIcon(t);
```

Comment: I need this program to display 3 random cards though which was what I thought I could do with the JLabels (sorry I forgot to specify this)